# How to merge common indices when creating MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
  Method Dataset  foo  bar
0     A1      B1   10   20
1     A1      B2   10   20
2     A1      B2   10   20
3     A2      B1   10   20
4     A3      B1   10   20
5     A1      B1   10   20
6     A2      B2   10   20
7     A3      B2   10   20
```

I'd like to use `Method` and `Dataset` columns to turn this into a MultiIndex DataFrame. So I tried doing:

```
df.set_index(["Method", "Dataset"], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Which gives:

```
Method Dataset          
A1     B1        10   20
       B1        10   20
       B2        10   20
       B2        10   20
A2     B1        10   20
       B2        10   20
A3     B1        10   20
       B2        10   20
```

This is almost what I want but I was expecting to see common values in `Dataset` index to also be merged under one value, i.e. similar to `Method` index:

```
                foo  bar
Method Dataset         
A1     B1       10   20
                10   20
       B2       10   20
                10   20
A2     B1       10   20
       B2       10   20
A3     B1       10   20
       B2       10   20
```

How can I achieve that?

(This might not make a big difference to how you'd use a DataFrame but I'm trying to use the `to_latex()` method which is sensitive to these things)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do this at the very end right before you write the DataFrame to_latex, otherwise you can have issues with data processing.

We will make the duplicated entries in the last level the empty string and reconstruct the entire MultiIndex.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
             df.index.get_level_values('Method'),
             np.where(df.index.duplicated(), '', df.index.get_level_values('Dataset'))
            ], names=['Method', 'Dataset'])
```

---

```
                foo  bar
Method Dataset          
A1     B1        10   20
                 10   20
       B2        10   20
                 10   20
A2     B1        10   20
       B2        10   20
A3     B1        10   20
       B2        10   20
```

---

If you want to make this a bit more flexible for any number of levels (even just a simple Index) we can use this function which will replace in the last level:

```
def white_out_index(idx):
    """idx : pd.MultiIndex or pd.Index"""
    i0 = [idx.get_level_values(i) for i in range(idx.nlevels-1)]
    i0.append(np.where(idx.duplicated(), '', idx.get_level_values(-1)))

    return pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(i0, names=idx.names)


df.index = white_out_index(df.index)
```